# Excel 2016 crashed when vba use saveas method on new application

Tags: vba, excel

I try to use Workbook.SaveAs method to save a new workbook with a specific name. I found it runs fine within the Application which the code run on. But caused excel crash with a new application. What's the problem?
Excel 2016 on Windows 10 Pro.
Codes below:

```
Sub test()
    Dim this_app As Application
    Set this_app = Application
    Dim new_app As Application
    Set new_app = New Application
    new_app.Visible = True
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = this_app.Workbooks.Add
    wb.SaveAs Filename:="new_file_name1"
'above SaveAs succeed
    Set wb = new_app.Workbooks.Add
    wb.SaveAs Filename:="new_file_name2"
'above SaveAs cause excel crash
End Sub
```

If I use `SaveCopyAs` method (code below), both is fine. But I still want to know why `SaveAs` caused Excel crashed.

```
Sub test()
    Dim this_app As Application
    Set this_app = Application
    Dim new_app As Application
    Set new_app = New Application
    new_app.Visible = True
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = this_app.Workbooks.Add
    wb.SaveCopyAs Filename:="new_file_name1.xlsx"
'above SaveCopyAs succeed
    Set wb = new_app.Workbooks.Add
    wb.SaveCopyAs Filename:="new_file_name2.xlsx"
'above SaveCopyAs also succeed
End Sub
```

Comment: Does it work now, when you have changed `app.Visible` to `new_app.Visible`?

Comment: No, it just a typing mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me (Excel 2013):

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim this_app    As Application
    Set this_app = Application
    Dim new_app     As Application
    Set new_app = New Application

    new_app.Visible = True

    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = this_app.Workbooks.Add
    wb.SaveAs Filename:="new_file_name11"

'above SaveAs sucessed
    Set wb = new_app.Workbooks.Add
    wb.SaveAs Filename:="new_file_name22"
'above SaveAs cause excel crash

End Sub
```

I suppose that your problem was in `app.Visible` or that you already had a file named `new_file_name2`, thus it crashed. Try changing the files and always add `Option Explicit` on the top of your code.

Comment: app.Visible should be `new_app.Visible`, it's a typing error. The work path is empty, no file there. I have tried `Option Explicit` but not help.